# File opening weird after PDF conversion

Tags: python, pdf, python-3.6

After stripping the text from a PDF into a text (.txt) file with the pdftotext terminal command (I'm running Ubuntu 17.04) then trying to read from the file, I am getting really weird output. I tested the code with a txt that had a single word in it: test. The code worked. It printed from the file perfectly, which tells me that it is either pdftotext's fault or the encoding's fault. What really gets me and made me come here is that the file opens in text editors normally, and all tests say that the file is in standard UTF-8. Here is my my [PDF stripped text file](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/635098/CM_2125.txt), created with:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import subprocess
from subprocess import *
import os
from tkinter import Listbox
import sys
from tkinter import Scrollbar
from tkinter import Frame
from tkinter import Label
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import Button

#win32, cygwin, linux, linux2, darwin

def chooser():
    returnedValue['filename'] = askopenfilename(**opts)
    try:
        subprocess.run(['pdftotext', returnedValue['filename'], '-raw'], check = True)
    except (TypeError, subprocess.CalledProcessError) as e:
        messagebox.showerror("Null error", "No file selected")
    if sys.platform == "linux" or sys.platform == "linux2" or sys.platform == "darwin":
        label = returnedValue['filename'].split('/')
        file2['file2'] = label[len(label)-1]
    else:
        label = returnedValue['filename'].split('\\')
        file2['file2'] = label[len(label)-1]

    L.insert(0, label[len(label)-1])

def trello():
    with open(returnedValue['filename'], 'r', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as f:
        content = f.readlines()
    content = [x.strip() for x in content]
    for line in content:
        print(line)


opts = {}
opts['filetypes'] = [('Portable Document Format','.pdf'),('all files','.*')]
opts['defaultextension'] = '.pdf'
opts['title'] = 'Select File'
opts['initialdir'] = [os.path.expanduser('~/')]

returnedValue = {}
returnedValue['filename'] = ""
file2 = {}
file2['file2'] = ""
root = tkinter.Tk()

B = Button(root, text = "Convert PDF", command = chooser)
B.pack()

F = Frame(root)

La = Label(F, text="PDFs Converted:")
La.pack()

S = Scrollbar(F)
S.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT, fill=tkinter.Y)

L = Listbox(F, height=5, yscrollcommand=S.set)
L.pack()

S.config(command=L.yview)

F.pack()

Bue = Button(root, text="Send to Trello", command = trello)
Bue.pack()

root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(500, 500))
root.attributes("-topmost", True)
root.wm_title("PDF Chooser")
root.mainloop()
```

This is the error I get when I don't use `errors='ignore'` in the `open()` function:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "./pdftotextCVM.py", line 34, in trello
    content = f.readlines()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 11:     invalid start byte
```

And [here](http://pastebin.com/mt4ShaER) is what I get when I do use `errors=ignore`. That last paste is as far back as my Ubuntu terminal history goes back, so there may be more, but you get the idea. Side note: If you couldn't tell, I am using Python 3.6.

Comment: Use a hex dump utility to see the actual file contents.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. You got me on the trail then dwarring found the answer.

Comment: Please do not use an external link for your code but copy it inside your post – preferably as a [mcve]. I've gone ahead and done it for you (the copying, not the limiting to the actual problem). I was unable to download and include the sample output, though; you'll have to do so yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrolling down, past the binary junk, from the [errors=ignore](http://pastebin.com/mt4ShaER) output, I see:

```
22 0 obj
<<
/Type /Font
/Subtype /Type0
/BaseFont /OXSVSB+TimesNewRoman/Encoding /Identity-H
/ToUnicode 23 0 R
/DescendantFonts[ 24 0 R ]
>>
```

Those are PDF instructions. Seems as if the input `.pdf`. file is being opened, not the output `.txt` file.

The `trello()` function probably needs to change the extension from `.pdf` to `.txt` before opening the file.